# Get string from URL containing hyphen/dash (-)

Tags: php, get

I have tried to GET a string from a URL, for instance
'www.example.com/store/samsung-A5-2016'

I want to get 'samsung-A5-2016' from the link with the $_GET method, but all I 'get' is "Samsung".

I want to get the whole string 'samsung-A5-2016'.

Comment: Depends on your rewrite rules whether you can get it from `$_GET`. Unless it's instead being passed and parsed by PHP, in which case it depends on what you're using.

Comment: Can you post the rewrite Rules you're using?

Comment: Is the URL text input, or an actual URL? Can you show how you are getting `Samsung` only currently?

Comment: I am using the .htaccess rewrite rule its like

Comment: RewriteRule ^store/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) store.php?d=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: You need to add the `-` at the beginning or the end of your character group.

Comment: @jeroen Nice catch :)

Comment: but the problem is that it makes the URL friendly, but doesn't let the $_GET variable get the whole name from the URL,
it only gets the first string before first (-)

Comment: See @jeroen's comment and answer. You're character class doesn't allow the `-` so the match ends at the `-`. If your regex where stricter and had the closing anchor (`$`) it wouldn't match at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `-` at the beginning or the end of your character group so that it does not define a range:

```
RewriteRule ^store/([-0-9a-zA-Z]+) store.php?d=$1 [NC,L] 
                     ^ Here you can add the - sign
```

Note that this only allows for the `-` sign in your urls, if you want others, you need to add these separately too.

Answer (score 0):

Please below rule for .htaccess
Because of currently your regex of .htaccess rule is not allowing '-' it gives string before the '-' of entire querystring value.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^store/(.*) store.php?d=$1 [L]
```